# My Wireless network disappears, however it shows other available networks

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I've been using a D-Link wireless modem with router and Win 7 PC. I face the following problem now. My Wireless network shows in the list of available networks during start-up, but disappears soon after. I've setup the connection so that it connects automatically to this network. Interestingly some other nearby networks are appearing in the list. 
I tried the following things.

1) Checked "Connect even if the network is not broadcasting its name (SSID)." in network properties.

2) Tried restarting PC, On/Off Modem etc.

3) I am able to use my wireless connection on Mobile.

Confusing thing is that it is showing other nearby networks. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the wireless network channel in your router settings

1. Log on to your router (something like 192.168.0.1).
2. Once logged in find your wireless settings page where you will see your network name.
3. There will be a drop down menu labelled "channel".
4. Try something like channel 11

Comment: Change the network to what? Is there a method for determining the best channel to use or is it just trial and error

Comment: Log on to your router (something like 192.168.0.1). Once logged in find your wireless settings page where you will see your network name. There will be a drop down menu labelled "channel".

Comment: Channel 11 is worth trying.

Comment: @Big Chris, your suggestion worked. In my case login to router was from 192.168.1.1. Thank you all.